# Destroy the whole hierarchy of objects at once

Tags: objective-c, opencv, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I have an object that holds a lot of smaller objects which holds a lot of smaller objects.
In order to clean the memory I want to be able to release all of the objects at once.

I'm using **ARC** so I thought that if I would just do `initialObject = nil` that would do the trick... But I don't see it working (memory is still in use).

The objects contains both objective-c AND c++ (openCV) code;

How can I achieve what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Create one data structure,which is a subclass of type NSobject and put one dealloc method in that and release all the smaller objects in that dealloc.Release your main object when your work is done.This is simple boss..

Comment: I can't use dealloc in ARC projects

Comment: @godmoney: Of course you can implement `dealloc` with ARC. ARC manages only the lifetime of Objective-C objects. If your class has other resources, you *have to* implement `dealloc` to release them.

Answer (score 0):

create weak references for smaller objects contained in your initial object. 
use __weak identifier. (for ARC)
When you set initialobject to nil, if there is no strong reference to your smaller objects, they get released.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variables referencing those objects to nil. The compiler will then release the objects at that moment and they will be destroyed if no other strong references to them exist.

Set that object which holds smaller object to nil, the set that object to nil.

That means u need to do is firstly set sub object to nil, which root object doesn't hold object, then set root object to nil, root object and sub object will be destroyed.